# Storing Api respond inside a variable Ionic

Tags: api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to store the respond for my call in variable then use it in my code but if I look at the console I get undefined

```
      getdata(){

          return this.http.get<any>('url', { headers: header })    
  }

    this.testProvider.getdata().subscribe(data => 
      {this.films=data.name
console.log(this.films);
    })
```

Comment: We need more information on that. How does the backend for this endpoint looks like? Is **data** also undefined?

Comment: no the data does show if I remove the .name{content: Array(2), pageable: {…}, totalPages: 1, totalElements: 2, last: true, …}content: Array(2)0: {id: 1, name: “test1, name_at: null,}1: {id: 2, name: "test", name_aa "test"}length: 2__proto__:

Answer (score 0):

You should do`this.films= data.content.name`

Edit: `this.films= data.content[index].name`

Comment: it also give me undefined

Comment: another thing I have set the films to be   films: Observable<any>; could that be the issue?

Comment: I can get the name if I did it like this but that a lot of steps  let x:any
     x=this.films
     console.log( x.content);

     for (let y of x.content){
      console.log (y.name)
     }

Comment: the issue were coming because  of the  films: Observable<any> I have change it to  films: any and it work fine now

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that you should do data.content[index].name because I see that it is an array for what you put in the comment above. Index will be 0 or 1 in that case that you have 2 elements